# Error: Could not find the correct Provider<DashboardBloc> above this DashboardPage Widget - FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, mobile, locking, lockscreen, touch-id

I'm new to flutter, I'm trying to allow my application once the user authentication is obtained to move to the DashboardPage, but I get this Error: Could not find the correct Provider  above this DashboardPage Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.

This is the code of my auth_page in both cases with code and biometric authentication must always lead to the DashboardPage () :

```
class AuthPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = '/fingerprint';

  Future<void> localAuth(BuildContext context) async {
    final localAuth = LocalAuthentication();
    final didAuthenticate = await localAuth.authenticateWithBiometrics(
        localizedReason: 'Please authenticate');
    if (didAuthenticate) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DashboardPage()),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            buildPinScreen(context),
            SizedBox(height: 24),
            SizedBox(height: 24),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

  Widget buildPinScreen(BuildContext context) => buildButton(
      text: 'UnLock',
      icon: Icons.lock_open,
      onClicked: () async {
        screenLock(context: context, correctString: '1234',
        canCancel: true,
           didUnlocked: (){
             Navigator.push(
               context,
               MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DashboardPage()),
             );
           },

       customizedButtonTap: () async {
        await localAuth(context);

       },
        didOpened: () async {
      await localAuth(context);

        },
        );
        }
     );
```

this is the code of my class route_configuration :

```
final router = FluroRouter();

class RouteConfiguration {
  static Future<void> register() async {
    // Register the routes
    router.define("/", handler: rootHandler);
    router.define(AssetFormScreen.routeName, handler: assetFormHandler);
    router.define(AssetTransferScreen.routeName, handler: assetTransferHandler);
    router.define(ShareAddressScreen.routeName, handler: shareAddressHandler);
    router.define(DashboardPage.routeName, handler: dashboardHandler);
  }
}
```

this is the code of my class route_handlers :

```
var rootHandler = Handler(
  type: HandlerType.route,
  handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, List<String>> params) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<MainBloc>(
          create: (_) => MainBloc(accountRepository: accountRepository),
        ),
        BlocProvider<NavigationBloc>(
          create: (_) => NavigationBloc(tabs[0]),
        ),
      ],
      child: MainScreen(),
    );
  },
);

var assetTransferHandler = Handler(
  handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, List<String>> params) {
    final asset = context?.settings?.arguments;
    if (asset is! AlgorandStandardAsset) return null;

    return BlocProvider(
      create: (_) =>
          AssetTransferBloc(accountRepository: accountRepository)..start(asset),
      child: AssetTransferScreen(),
    );
  },
);

var assetFormHandler = Handler(
  handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, List<String>> params) {
    return BlocProvider<AssetFormBloc>(
      create: (_) => AssetFormBloc(accountRepository: accountRepository),
      child: AssetFormScreen(),
    );
  },
);

var shareAddressHandler = Handler(
  handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, List<String>> params) {
    final address = params['address']?[0] ?? '';

    return BlocProvider<AssetFormBloc>(
      create: (_) => AssetFormBloc(accountRepository: accountRepository),
      child: ShareAddressScreen(
        address: address,
      ),
    );
  },
);

var dashboardHandler = Handler(
  handlerFunc: (BuildContext? context, Map<String, List<String>> params) {
    return BlocProvider<DashboardBloc>(
      create: (_) => DashboardBloc(accountRepository: accountRepository),
      child: DashboardPage(),
    );
  },
);
```

PLEASE HELP ME !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bloc is not readily available to all the new pages that you push in the stack or even to new widgets. To provide existing bloc to new page, you have to use bloc provider.

```
 Navigator.push(context,
   MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context1) =>
     BlocProvider.value(
      value: BlocProvider.of<BlocName>(context),
        child: DashboardPage())));
```

Comment: thank you very much ! in this way my page is loaded, but the colors are out of order and not the original ones, can you tell me why?

Comment: Do you mean the colors of DashboardPage ? If so then sorry, but I don't have any idea about that.